# Make a shiny UI (e.g. sliderInput) object vary based on the users input

Tags: r, shiny

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  shiny::titlePanel("Hurricane Maps"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(shiny::selectInput('names', 'Choosing something:', choices=c('A', 'B', 'C'),
                 shiny::sliderInput("duration", "Range of Storm:", min = should_vary,
                                    max =  should_vary, value = c( should_vary, should_vary)
                                    ))
  )
)
server <- function(input, output) {

}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

The above is the code.

I need the "should_vary" to vary based on whether A, B, or C was selected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to:

1. Use [`renderUI`](https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/0.14/renderUI.html) within shiny server part to programmatically create a UI object
2. This object should depend on the `names` ID (i.e. you have to make `input$names` reactive)
3. In the UI part you have to insert rendered object with `uiOutput`

Code:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  selectInput("names", "Choosing something:", c("A", "B", "C"), "A"),
  uiOutput("duration_rendered")
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  input_names <- reactive({
    switch(input$names, "A" = 1, "B" = 2, "C" = 3)
  })

  output$duration_rendered <- renderUI({
    sliderInput(
      "duration",
      "Range of Storm:",
      min = input_names(),
      max =  input_names() + 10,
      value = c(input_names(), input_names() + 10)
    )
  })

}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```